# CSS Keyframe animation flicking with Chrome v59.0.3071.109

Tags: css, google-chrome

With **latest Chrome v59.0.3071.109 update** I have realised that **keyframes animation might flicked**.

**CSS**

```
.rectangle {
  display:block;
  background:#AAA;
  margin:3em auto;
  width:30px;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow:
    inset #AAA 0 0 0 0,
    inset #222 0 0px 0 0;
  animation:filler 5s linear infinite;  
}  

@keyframes filler{
  0%{

    box-shadow:
      inset #AAA 0 0px 0 0,
      inset #222 0 0px 0 0;
  }
  100%{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    box-shadow:
      inset #AAA 0 0px 0 0,
      inset #222 0 50px 0 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Flick example">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**DEMO (please, check your Chrome version is v59.0.3071.109)**

https://jsbin.com/nameyi/edit?html,css,output

I have realised that if **I removed the rotate it seems to go better** but I would like to keep the rotate.

**Is there any way to avoid the flicking?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different way to achieve the same result, without flickering. The box-shadow is a very expensive operation, which causes flickering quite often.

```css
.rectangle {
  display: block;
  background: #AAA;
  margin: 3em auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  animation:rotater 5s linear infinite;
}

.rectangle:after {
  content: " ";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: filler 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes filler {
  from { height: 0px; }
  to { height: 50px; }
}


@keyframes rotater {
  from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```